# Передача параметра в функцию через функцию std::ref()

Tags: c++, c++11

В примере с потоками встретил передачу параметра через функцию **ref** из стандартной библиотеки, не ясно как ее использовать, почему нельзя передать переменную просто по ее имени?

Вот собственно сам пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void threadFunction(int &a)
{
     a++;
}

int main()
{
     int a = 1;
     std::thread thr(threadFunction, std::ref(a)); // что делает функция ref()? почему нельзя передовать просто переменную по ее имени?
     thr.join();
     std::cout << a << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

---

**добавлено позже**

при передачи просто по имени **std::thread thr(threadFunction, a);** программа не компилируется и падает с ошибкой

[image: консоль ошибок]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По имени - сохранится значение. А вам нужно просто синоним для той же области памяти. В результате, когда отработает `threadFunction` у вас напечатается 2. Если убрать `std::ref`, то 1.

А вот [тут](http://artlang.net/article/view/7/) более детальеное объяснение:

> Третья задача решается с помощью шаблонных функций `std::ref` и
>   `std::cref` объявленных в заголовке `<functional>`. Первая возвращает
>   ссылку на объект, вторая возвращает константную ссылку. Эти функции
>   очень часто нужны при работе, например, с `std::bind`. Причина одна -
>   передать в связыватель ссылку, а не копию объекта. Если Вы работаете с
>   потоками (`std::thread`) и Вам нужно передать аргументы по ссылке при
>   инициализации объекта потока, Вам также понадобятся функции `std::ref` и
>   `std::cref`.

Comment: при передачи просто по имени **std::thread thr(threadFunction, a);** программа не компилируется и падает с ошибкой

Comment: Ну так то да - конструктор thread ожидает `Args&&`, а тип `a` - `int&`, `ref` создаёт временный объект `reference_wrapper`, который удовлетворяет требованию rvalue.

Comment: @perfect измени **void threadFunction(int &a)** на **void threadFunction(int a)** и все будет компилироваться

Answer (score 1):

Подобные методы захватывают данные только по значению. Для того, чтобы прокинуть по ссылке и сделан данный враппер. В итоге получается что сам враппер далее копируется, но внутри себя продолжает удерживать ссылку.